# Can't get matlab.engine to work on M1 Mac

Tags: python, function, matlab

I have a `MacBook Pro M1` running on `Big Sur` with `python 3.8`, `Matlab R2020b`. Both running under rosetta2 perfectly fine.

Since I need to use one Matlab function, that I have in an python Script of me, I wanted to use Matlab.engine in my python script and followed the instructions with sudo privileges and `python3` instead of `python` on:

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html

Then I entered `python3` in the terminal and tried `import matlab.engine` which resulted in the error: `No module named 'matlab.engine'; 'matlab' is not a package`

My `.zshrc` file contains the Path to my Python. I tried `export PATH="/Users/flo/Library/Python/3.8/bin:$PATH"`and as that didn't work I also tried `export PATH="/Library/Python/3.8:$PATH"`

Matlab is also on my path, as I can call `matlab` from terminal and it starts, as expected. It's just the `matlab.engine` That I can't get running.

Since the only thing, that I want to achieve by it, is calling a script, containing a `function with 2 input and 7 output arguments` (which I need in python for further calculations), is there another way to do it without the need of `matlab.engine`, in case I can't get it running?

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, I could resolve the issue, that I had for quite some days, some minutes after posting the question..

It seems, I did the `pip3 install matlab` some weeks/months ago and didn't remember. When I tried to `import matlab.engine`, python thought, I want to import `engine` from the installed `matlab` from pip. And that's why I got the error, that matlab is not a package.

Simply do `pip3 uninstall matlab` resolved this issue for me!
Hope, this helps other people save the days, that I wasted with such a silly error..